# Making a Weather Forecast Widget, and I need to make 2 things happen using JSON and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Making a widget to broadcast the local weather.

Need to make a custom div button that changes the background of the whole html as an onClick function, and the other big thing I want to do is use a for loop to display 7 days, the week's, weather.

index.html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
              <h1 id="header">~Wonderful Weather Widget~</h1>
              <div id="days">
              <div id="content">
              <div id="place"></div>
              <div id="day"></div>
              <div id="conditions"></div>
              <div id="conditionsDesc"></div>
              <div id="currentTemp"></div>
              </div>
              </div>
           <script src="script.js"></script>
        </section>
        <article>
        <div id='openweathermap-widget'></div>
                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                    window.myWidgetParam = {
                        id: 15,
                        cityid: 5780993,
                        appid: 'bb80d6b0bf0dbcf02f65eff720397c3b',
                        containerid: 'openweathermap-widget',
                    };
                    (function() {
                        var script = document.createElement('script');
                        script.type = 'text/javascript';
                        script.async = true;
                        script.src = 'http://openweathermap.org/themes/openweathermap/assets/vendor/owm/js/weather-widget-generator.js';
                        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                        s.parentNode.insertBefore(script, s);
                    })();
                  </script>

                <div id="clouds" class="box">Cloudy</div>

    </article>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.css code:

```
html{
    background-image: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/56/73/6e/56736e99269e9e1fe8eed4b8b911644e.gif);
    background-size: cover;
}

#openweathermap-widget{
    padding: 25px;
}

#header{
    background: #000;
    color: #bef;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 55px;
    font-family: cursive;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    opacity: .7;
}

#days{
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 0px;
    padding: 10px;

}
```

JavaScript code:

```
var weatherData;
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
var date = new Date();

loadData();

function loadData() {

    request.open('GET', 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Salt+Lake+City,us&units=imperial&cnt=5&appid=bb80d6b0bf0dbcf02f65eff720397c3b');
    request.onload = loadComplete;
    request.send();
}

function loadComplete(evt) {
    weatherData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    console.log(weatherData);
    document.getElementById("place").innerHTML = weatherData.city.name;
    document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = (date.getMonth()+1) + "/" + date.getDate();
    document.getElementById("currentTemp").innerHTML = weatherData.list[0].temp.day;
    document.getElementById("conditions").innerHTML = weatherData.list[0].weather[0].main;
    document.getElementById("conditionsDesc").innerHTML = weatherData.list[0].weather[0].description;  
}
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('#clouds').on("click", function(){
       $('html').css('background-image', 'url(http://i236.photobucket.com/albums/ff234/snookies56/NATURE/29707055_IMG_3485sani.gif)');
     });
}
```

All help welcome, and thank you guys for the assistance. :)

Comment: What was the problem? What error are you getting?

Comment: I made the loop to make the other 5 days, however I can not get them to display, and the css issue is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'main' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.loadComplete (script.js:22)